# Can I undo an accept?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a [question about mobile data plan in France](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8642/can-i-buy-a-prepaid-mobile-data-plan-while-on-route-in-france). One of the answers seemed to be good, alas I accepted. However, while travelling in France I learnt that the answer is incorrect. Both solutions don't sell mobile plans.

How can I delete the accept?

Comment: If you did find out a solution on your trip, I'd also suggest adding it as an answer to your own question for the benefit of the rest of us. :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to just click the green tick next to the accepted answer.

I've just tried this with one I accepted on a question, and indeed, it worked.

If that fails, let me know if there's an error or something?

Comment: It worked. This example shows not to be soquick in accepting an answer