# How does an accepted answer become unaccepted?

Tags: support

[Japanese destination airports with lower costs? (from US airports)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27344/japanese-destination-airports-with-lower-costs-from-us-airports) had one answer, and it was a good one.  A day or two ago, I added a little detail to it, and clicked to accept it.  The green check mark *did* appear.

I went to that page today, click on some of the links, and it was not marked as accepted.  I know I can un-accept, but I didn't.  Are others allowed to do it?

I re-accepted it.

Answer (score 6):

No, only you accept / unaccept answers of your questions, high reputation users and moderators can't do it.

So I assume that there was some problem with the website.

Answer (score 5):

It looks accepted to me?  You can un-accept an answer by clicking its checkmark again.

See also: [Can I undo an accept?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/840/can-i-undo-an-accept)